# Solving $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{2^{\sqrt{\log x}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to solve $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x^2}{2^{\sqrt{\log x}}}$$ using L'Hopital and a little of Algebra, but still I can't solve it. Using L'Hopital is horrible due to the third derivative of $2^\sqrt{\log x}$, which still can't help to solve it.

Wolframalpha says that it diverges to infinity, but still I can't solve it. Is there a method that can help?

Comment: Hint: $\log f(x) = 2 \log x - (\log 2) \sqrt{\log x}$.

Comment: When $\ln x > 1, 2^{\sqrt {\ln x}} < 2^{\ln x} < e^{\ln x} = x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $\sqrt{\log x}=u$ as $u\to\infty$, then you have

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{2^{\sqrt{\log x}}}&=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{e^{2u^2}}{2^u}\\
&=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^{2u}}{2}\right)^u\\
&\longrightarrow+\infty.\end{align}$$

Comment: Very good your approach.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for reviewing my answer.. ( ◜‿◝ )

Comment: You are very good in Maths and for to make the strange emoji.

Comment: @Sebastiano I know I'm not good, but many thanks again for encouraging me ( ◜‿◝ )

Answer (score 3):

Hint: It is possible to show that
$$
\frac{x^2}{2^{\sqrt{\log(x)}}} \geq \frac{x}{2}.
$$
Then you see that the expression goes to $\infty$ for $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Very nice also this answer. Intuitive :-)

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ 2^{\sqrt{\log n}} = 2^{\left(\frac{\log n}{\sqrt{\log n}}\right)} \le
n ^ {1/\sqrt{\log n}} $$
everything is clear！